# GoogleMap crash when I set value to UserDefault - UserDefaults.standard.set("km", forKey: APPLE_LANGUAGE_KEY)

Tags: swift, google-maps, localization, crash

I'm working on an Application that supported 3 languages and that application also integrated with GoogleMap SDK.

The way I localize my application is by changing the value for key `AppleLanguages`

The moment I set the value to `AppleLanguages`, my next build will be crashed when I get into Map screen.

My localization code:

```
var localized: String {
        let languageKey = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: APPLE_LANGUAGE_KEY) ?? "en"
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: languageKey, ofType: "lproj")
        let bundle = Bundle.init(path: path!)! as Bundle

        return bundle.localizedString(forKey: self, value: nil, table: nil)
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @henrik-dmg: here's the error message.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'GMSx_GMMClientPropertiesRequestProto.screenPixelDensity: Attempt to set an unknown enum value (0)'
***

Comment: Hmm this sounds more like a bug in the SDK for me, not in your code

Comment: I'm trying to find the solution to this problem but don't seem to have any other discussions then `localization`.

Comment: Does this crash also happen when return just a random string in this computed property? Like have tried narrowing down the issue to this specific snippet?

Comment: Not yet. But I noticed that as long as the UserDefault for key "AppleLanguages" has value, the map crash on the next build.

Comment: It might interfer with the Google Maps SDK then, a rule of thumb is to always have as unique as possible identifiers for user defaults keys. For example you could try adding a unique prefix to each key you store yourself (e.g. "yourAppName_")

Comment: Wait a minute, Why didn't I think of that before. I've changed the UserDefault's key and it works fine now.

OMG Thank you so much <3